# Use a custom layout to badge xamarin.Android's action bar menu items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[Check my action bar image here(My requirement)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqlC1.png)i want to display the custom text label button on  xamarin.android action bat(material theme),is there any possibility to do that in xamarin.android please suggest ...

```
static Button notifCount;
static int mNotifCount = 0;    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    View count = menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();
    notifCount = (Button) count.findViewById(R.id.notif_count);
    notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setNotifCount(int count){
    mNotifCount = count;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}


i tried above code converting into xamarin.android but it is showing like..

View count= menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.badge).getActionView ...Error...getActionview is not there in xamarin.
```

Comment: Is there a `GetActionView` method or an `ActionView` property? Xamarin often renames methods and converts getter & setters to properties.

Comment: ActionView  property is there in xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my post about this on the Xamarin Forums. Just did this recently for Push Notifications, though I am not sure if your badge is for Push or Local Notifications. I am using Xamarin Forms so it may be a little different from you but let me know if you have any issues.

Basically, in `OnCreateOptionsMenu` you make sure you are on your specific page, then inflate your custom badge into the action bar and then add a custom action.

Then in `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` you can update the badge count. I used the DB to figure out what the new badge value should be.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/183694/#Comment_183694

*Edit: I also found [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31244/box-view-with-rounded-corners-badge-with-counter-snippets) recently but have not looked into it much. Might also be helpful.